# Spring data: How to change EntityManager at runtime

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, entitymanager

In my project I have a series of interfaces that extends "JpaRepository". 
I need to filter the entity manager with data that arrives from the Http Request.
At runtime whenever the app use a repository I need to change the instance of the EntityManager with another instance.
Is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: Please rephrase your question as it doesn't properly address your scenario.

Comment: It's hard  to understand what you're asking for. My take on your scenario is that you have several data sources, and the request need to pick which one to use based on some request parameter. You intend to use a separate entity manager for each data source, and are asking if it's possible and how to set it up. Is this a correct interpretation of your question?